# Why is this question getting so many down votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

[Could Gothic ahs (ear of grain) and Turkish ak (white) be cogante?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/35336/could-gothic-ahs-ear-of-grain-and-turkish-ak-white-be-cogante) , by user [Nurlan](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/27639/nurlan), is receaving many downvotes, however, for me, it is but a simple question of someone with a doubt. Of course, once you know a bit more about linguistics you know it is difficult to have such cognates between languages and it sounds a weird question, but I don't see the problem with that, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even once the edit war was resolved/locked, it's still an extremely poor question. The down button explicitly says that it is to be used for unresearched questions. Etymology questions [also have a generally poor reception here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1838/2555).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intermediately, the OP had edited their question so as to completely eliminate the question content and have the post say "I want to delete my own question!" instead. It is possible that (part of) the downvotes accumulated while this non-question was up before I restored the original version.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't saw it! Thank you!

Comment: Considering that this is new name of the "samuelvirtanen" account, I don't expect the story to end here.

Comment: It's happening again, despite @prash's attempt to put a lid on it. Why was the post unlocked by "Community"? Might the only way to stop this be to ban Nurlan?

Comment: @Nardog That was my slip-up. I accidentally locked the post for one hour (only). That's why the "Community" bot unlocked it. I have now corrected my mistake and locked the post permanently.